# CUDA: get required compute capabilities from binary

Tags: cuda

Is there a way to get the required compute capabilites from a binary file which uses CUDA? I know the application works with a specific graphics card (which has compute capabilities 2.1).

Comment: What sort of binary file are you asking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `cuobjdump` should help you out here. It will tell you what *ptx* (code for jit compiling at runtime) is available in a compiled file and what *sass* (real code that gets executed on a specific device) has been precompiled as well. Below an example output for device code compiled with `-arch=sm_20`:

```
$ cuobjdump quick

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,7]
producer = <unknown>
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = quick.cu

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = quick.cu

Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_20
code version = [4,1]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed
identifier = quick.cu
ptxasOptions =  --generate-line-info
```